# AWS disable cognito federated identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So my app authenticates user using aws cognito and facebook login, I manage to make the authentication work, now my problem is I need to disable or deactivated user from authenticating from my app, for cognito users I can just use my userpool and disable the account, but how can I do the same for facebook users? Is it possible to disable/deactivate users using the federated identity?